# Drupal + WYSIWYG + TinyMCE / Not all Buttons/Plugins showing up

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tinymce, wysiwyg

I've got Drupal installed with the WYSIWYG Module and TinyMCE. I've selected a number of Buttons/Plugins:
[image: WYSIWYG Plugin Order]

Unfortunately about a third aren't showing up:
[image: TinyMCE Buttons]

I don't see any errors. Status report is clean, caches cleared, browser history erased. Ideas?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the "Group" they're in. All the 'default' ones are showing up. 'Spellchecker' shows up... but almost none of the rest.

edit:

Looking at the source I see "theme_advanced_buttons1" is being set, and all the of modules listed:

> "theme_advanced_buttons1":"bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,undo,redo,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,fontselect,fontsizeselect,sup,sub,blockquote,hr,cut,copy,paste,removeformat,advhr,spellchecker,drupal_media,drupal_syntaxhighlighter_insert_wysiwyg,drupal_linebreaks,drupal_convert_linebreaks,drupal_break","theme_advanced_buttons2":"","theme_advanced_buttons3":""

Comment: The button groups are added to a profile of text editing what groups do you have? what one did you add these buttons to and which one is standard selected. For example i usually add all these buttons to "Full html" But my node editing usually starts with "Filtered html". So to see the buttons i have to switch to full html.

Comment: @melvin I've only got "Full HTML" configured to use TinyMCE. The above screenshots were taken with "Full HTML" selected.

Comment: Ok well that takes away my first guess not sure if i can help you then. I tried installing the module myself but looks differnt then yours. So if you can at least post your version of the wysywig module, the version of TinyMCE and the (minor) version of drupal i might see what is wrong.

Comment: @melvin: sure thing. Drupal 7.27, WYSIWYG 7.x-2.2+33-dev, WYSIWYG Button Order 7.x-1.0-rc1, TinyMCE 3.5.8

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I appear to have resolved this problem. I haven't tracked down exactly where is issue is, but after disabling the WYSIWYG module, moving aside the module directory:

```
mv {site base}/sites/all/modules/wysiwyg {site base}/sites/all/modules/wysiwyg.bak
```

and then downloading a fresh version of the module most of the Plugins now show. I'm chalking up the couple that aren't showing up yet to issues with the actual Plugins and not an issue in the WYSIWYG module.